# Product of two subspaces - contradiction?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Okay so in my lecture notes the product of two subspaces A and B is defined as the span of  dot products for each pair of spanning vectors in A and B. Here in Exercise 6.45 using this definition we get A.B as the span of the four unit indicator vectors. This means we have A.B = R^4, correct?

Well, in 6.46 we are to demonstrate that the product of subspaces is not necessarily itself a subspace, using 6.45... Huh? If A.B is R^4 then surely it is a subspace. e_1 + e_4 = (1,0,0,1) is absolutely in A.B as it was defined in 6.45. But the next part shows that no two vectors from A and B can produce the dot product of (1,0,0,1) so surely A.B can't be R^4... So what's going on here?

Comment: That definition of the product of two subspaces doesn't make much sense.  Dot products as ordinarily referenced are scalars.  What is the span of a set of scalars?  Either your dot product means something else ("pointwise product"??) or the lecture notes you have are garbled.

Comment: Yes, sorry he's defined dot product to be the pointwise product. So x.y is (x1.y1, x2.y2, ..., xn.yn)

Comment: Okay, note writers are allowed to define things as they please.  But then you say the product of the subspaces is a certain *span* of a set of vectors, in which case we will certainly get a subspace (even if the set is empty or contains some linearly dependent vectors).  Again the prospect that the lecture notes are garbled suggests itself.  One needs to establish that the resulting "product of subspaces" does not depend on the choice of "pairs of spanning vectors".  Perhaps the pairs of spanning vectors here means all vectors $u\in A$ and $v\in B$.

Comment: For what it's worth the top line of Exer. 6.46 seems to say not that a "product of subspaces" as you've quoted a definition is not a subspace, but that a set of pointwise products generated from sets $S_1,S_2$ need not be a subspace.  This looks to be an easy exercise.